# Como posicionar um elemento em relação a outro facilmente?

Tags: html, css

Estou criando meio que uma loja online, mas não estou conseguindo estilizar direito o meu HTML, eu gostaria que as `<div>s` vazias (coloquei div no exemplo só para ilustrar, mas na verdade são imagens), ficassem com o preço na parte de baixo, no caso criei uma outra div com a class `.linha`, mas o que está acontecendo, é que não estou sabendo manusear bem as posições.

Como eu faço isso?

Um exemplo de como eu quero:

[image: Feito no Paint =D]

O que eu tenho até agora:

```css
.imagem {
 background-color: black;
 border-radius: 10px;
 width:200px;
 height:260px;
 margin-left: 55px;
}
.linha{
 bottom: 125px;
 background-color: #2aabd2;
 width: 200px;
 height: 40px;
 position: absolute;
    border: 4px solid #99ccff;
 border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
.pontocartao{
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "Arial Black";
 color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top:100px">
 <div class="imagem"></div>
 <div class="imagem linha"><p class="pontocartao">10 pontos</p></div>
 <div class="imagem"></div>
 <div class="imagem linha"><p class="pontocartao">50 pontos</p></div>
 <div class="imagem"></div>
 <div class="imagem linha"><p class="pontocartao">50 pontos</p></div>
 <div class="imagem"></div>
 <div class="imagem linha"><p class="pontocartao">50 pontos</p></div>
 <div class="imagem"></div>
 <div class="imagem linha"><p class="pontocartao">50 pontos</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja um [artigo](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_gallery.asp) sobre galeria da W3schools que eu imagino combinar muito com o que você deseja fazer.

Para resumir o código seria esse:

```css
div.gallery{margin:5px;border:1px solid #ccc}
div.gallery img{width:100%;height:auto}
div.desc{padding:15px;text-align:center;}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/p1DYtzb.png" alt="imagem">
<div class="desc">Descrição/no seu caso preço</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/74)

Comment: Obrigado pela crítica

Answer (score 0):

Tente criar uma div onde ela vai conter tanto a imagem que você deseja quanto outra div com o preço. Feito isso tente colocar 'display: block' na imagem e na div do preço, isso fará com que o conteúdo da div mais externa fique uns sobre os outros.